# iTextsharp : AcroFields - Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary' to type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfArray'

Tags: c#-4.0, itext, acrofields

I am trying to Load a Form PDF using iTextsharp. When i tried to set the value for a field element in that PDF using Acrofield, am getting "Invalid Cast Exception". "Error Converting IDictionary Object type to Array".

We are using itextSharp 5.* version

Error Stack Trace :

Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary' to type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfArray'.

```
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.Fill()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields..ctor(PdfReader reader, PdfWriter writer)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.GetAcroFields()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper.get_AcroFields()
   at generate_PDF.WebForm1.generate_PDF() in c:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\generate_PDF\generate_PDF\PDF.aspx.cs:line 159
  at generate_PDF.WebForm1.BtnPrint_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\465816\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\generate_PDF\generate_PDF\PDF.aspx.cs:line 32
  at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
  at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
  at System.
```

Please find the form in below Link as well.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3W8aJry8ZMERnJubHpMdVk5SmM/view?usp=sharing

But the same code is working for other PDF form.
Please Let me know the reason the reason for getting this Error, is this becasue of the PDF ? or any other issue.

Comment: Can you share the form? It sounds as if there's an error in the form...

Comment: Can you share the form? It sounds as if there's an error in the form...

Comment: Hi Bruno, Please check the below Link for ref. [https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3W8aJry8ZMERnJubHpMdVk5SmM]

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3W8aJry8ZMERnJubHpMdVk5SmM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

The cause for that exception is that the AcroForm PDF form description in your sample PDF is invalid.

---

In the **AcroForm** interactive form dictionary of your PDF (object 200) the value of the **Fields** key is a dictionary object (object 201):

```
201 0 obj
<<
/T(ŸJ˜OPZ?h&7·Œ]VŸÄþ)
/Kids[ 190 0 R 191 0 R 192 0 R]
>>
endobj
200 0 obj
<<
/DR 194 0 R
/XFA[(uÕêÒãÊ\0224) 195 0 R(fÈáÕçÏ) 196 0 R(qÂâÃâÉ\0124) 197 0 R(aÆûÒýÍ\012") 198 0 R(uÈüÇïÅ\034=O) 199 0 R]
/Fields 201 0 R
/NeedAppearances true
>>
endobj
```

But the specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) clearly specifies

> **Fields** array *(Required)* An array of references to the document’s root fields (those with no ancestors in the field hierarchy).
>
> *(Table 218 – Entries in the interactive form dictionary )*

So that value **must** be an array.

Please ask the source of the file to supply a valid PDF.